# Why Object [ID] has no method 'Animate'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, jquery-animate

I've created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/surfjam/zWWpz/

I can't figure out why animate works in two instances, but not in another. In the console error says "...no method 'Animate'..."

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var effect = "inm-shine";

    $(".circle-button-border").mouseenter(function() {

        $(this).addClass(effect);

        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
            opacity: '0.85'
        }, 'slow').css({
            'z-index': '100',
            top: '0',
            left: '0'
        });

//Error coming from this line...

        $(this).parents('div:eq(0)').attr('id').animate({
            height: '120%',
            left: '0',
            top: '0',
            width: '120%'
        }, 'fast');

    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: '0'
        }, 'fast');
    });
});​
```

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks to the suggestions below, I've reworked the problem line like this:

```
var myId = $(this).parents('div:eq(0)').attr('id');
        $('#' + myId).animate({
            height: '110%',
            left: '0',
            top: '0',
            width: 110%
        }, 'fast');
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `attr('id')` returns the value of the *id* attribute.

Comment: comment from gumbo is right. you're trying to do an animation on a string not on the jquery-object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`attr('id')` is returning a string, so you no longer have the chained jQuery object.